# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on jetty + nginx

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nginx, jetty, blueimp

I am uploading files and for few files i am getting

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I checked my code logs there seems to be no error, I doubt it might be related to somewhere with proxy server.

i also checked configured client_max_body_size in nginx.conf which is 2000M and my request file size is in few kilo bytes.

can some one help me as i am not able to figure out what to look for this issue?

I am using Jetty Server(9.3.8.v20160314) and nginx-1.10.2 is my proxy server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps specific details about the version of nginx and jetty would help people diagnose the issue.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Added Versions in Question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an issue with nginx regarding the size of the file you are uploading.

nginx fails, sends a 413 response and closes the connection when the client body is bigger than the client_max_body_size.

What's the size of the file you're trying to upload ?

Try to change the nginx configuration (5MB for example):

```
client_max_body_size 5M;
```

Comment: client_max_body_size is not the issue here in my case